# Can not Get RecyclerView Item Position to Delete from SQLite

Tags: java, android

I created ActionMode.Callback method to inflate the ActionBar. I succeeded in inflating the ActionBar but my problem with clicking on the delete item on the ActionBar.
I do not know how to get the position of RecyclerView Item so I can delete it from SQLite Database.

Here my code.

```
public class ViewList extends AppCompatActivity {
FloatingActionButton fab, fabDel;
RecyclerView rv;

DatabaseHelper dbh;
ArrayList<Data> myValues = new ArrayList<>();
DataAdapter dataAdapter;
ActionMode mActionMode;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_list);

    dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fabDel = findViewById(R.id.fab_del);

    Cursor data = dbh.getListContents();

    if (data.getCount() != 0) {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            String str1 = data.getString(1);
            String str2 = data.getString(2);
            Data d = new Data(str1, str2);
            myValues.add(d);
            dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(myValues);
            rv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
    }else {
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent activityMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(activityMain);
            }
        });

        return;
    }

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent mainactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainactivity);
        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }
            mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                dbh.delete();
                myValues.remove();
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mode.finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.edit:
                Toast.makeText(ViewList.this, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mode.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
};
```

}

Adapter Class

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder>{
private ArrayList<Data> myValues;
private RecyclerViewItemClickListener recyclerViewItemClickListener;
private Context context;
private DatabaseHelper dbh;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv_title, tv_des;
    public int position = 0;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_des = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                recyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(v,position);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setOnItemClickListener (RecyclerViewItemClickListener recyclerViewItemClickListener) {
    this.recyclerViewItemClickListener = recyclerViewItemClickListener;
}

public DataAdapter(ArrayList<Data> myValues) {
    this.myValues = myValues;
    dbh = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tv_title.setText(myValues.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tv_des.setText(myValues.get(position).getDescription());
    long id = myValues.get(position).getId();
    holder.itemView.setTag(id);
    holder.position = position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myValues.size();
}
```

}

My Model Class

```
public class Data {
private String title, description;
private long id;

public Data() {
}

public Data(String title, String description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

DatabaseHelper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data";
public static final String COL1 = "id";
public static final String COL2 = "ITEM1";
public static final String COL3 = "ITEM2";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "ITEM1 TEXT, ITEM2 TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(createTable);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
}

public boolean addData(String item1, String item2) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item1);
    contentValues.put(COL3, item2);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
}

public Cursor getListContents() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return data;
}

public void delete(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
}
```

}

Comment: you have to give position to remove method

Comment: I know, I explained above that I do not have any positions to pass to the delete method.

Comment: please add adapter code and your activity code

Comment: All were added.

Comment: you want to delete multiple data ?

Comment: yes, any items I want like selecting some items and delete them or maybe only one item and delete it

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Some fact exist that you have to pay attention.

Setting  click listener in ViewHolder is not correct, since RecyclerView cache by default viewholders it creates. So the position is not always retrieved  correctly in your code. In this regard i make some changes to access the position, and flee from this situation.

Change you Viewholder class as following and remove click listener from it:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv_title, tv_des;
    public int position = 0;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv_des = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_des);
    }
}
```

Then change on bindViewHolder like following code snippet and assign the listener there:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tv_title.setText(myValues.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.tv_des.setText(myValues.get(position).getDescription());
    long id = myValues.get(position).getId();
    holder.itemView.setTag(id);
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                recyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemLongClick(v,position);
                return true;
            }
        });
}
```

now you have access to position correctly.

***EDIT:***

Since RecyclerView cache ViewHolders, then it would reuse view holder object for multiple rows which are not visible. So some properties like position would be overridden. but onbindViewHolder will be invoked every time a new row is attaching to visible part of screen, with correct position. So I removed listener from ViewHolder and put in onViewHolderBind.

pay attention to following example:

assume that you have 4 row of data and only 3 of them are visible. In start time since only 3 rows will become visible, recycler view create 3 view holder objects, and assign them to ui, if cache of RecyclerView is active and is active by default, when you scroll upward to see 4th row, recyclerview to manage memory will use viewholder object which become created for first row which is going to be invisible.

Is it clear? or you need some extra explanation? don't hesitate if you need more.

Comment: dude doesnt make sense

Comment: I'm adding some extra explanation to post. check it few minutes later

Comment: I did it, but still the same problem. My problem is I can not find any position variables to pass in the dbh.delete(); method in the main class.

Comment: ok, let me check it and i will edit the message to give you solution

Comment: check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

**try this Hope it help**

```html
public class ViewList extends AppCompatActivity {
FloatingActionButton fab, fabDel;
RecyclerView rv;

DatabaseHelper dbh;
ArrayList<Data> myValues = new ArrayList<>();
DataAdapter dataAdapter;
ActionMode mActionMode;
int pos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_list);

    dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    rv = findViewById(R.id.rv);
    fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fabDel = findViewById(R.id.fab_del);

    Cursor data = dbh.getListContents();

    if (data.getCount() != 0) {
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            String str1 = data.getString(1);
            String str2 = data.getString(2);
            Data d = new Data(str1, str2);
            myValues.add(d);
            dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(myValues);
            rv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        }
    }else {
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent activityMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(activityMain);
            }
        });

        return;
    }

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent mainactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mainactivity);
        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        pos = position;
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }
            mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
                dbh.delete(arraylist.get(pos).getId);// what ever your getter setter name is
                myValues.remove(pos);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mode.finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.edit:
                Toast.makeText(ViewList.this, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mode.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        mActionMode = null;
    }
};
```

Declare the variable globally

```
 int pos;
```

Pass the position to this variable like this

```
    dataAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        pos = position;
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }
            mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

And Use that variable to Delete like this:

```
      case R.id.delete:
                dbh.delete(myValues.get(pos).getId);// what ever your getter setter name is
                myValues.remove(pos);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mode.finish();
                return true;
```

Add the id to Model Constructor

```
public Data(long id,String title, String description) {
this.title = title;
this.description = description;
this.id= id;
 }
```

set the Id :

Cursor data = dbh.getListContents();

```
    if (data.getCount() != 0) {
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        String str1 = data.getString(1);
        String str2 = data.getString(2);
        long id = Long.valueOf(getInt(3))
        Data d = new Data(id,str1, str2);
        myValues.add(d);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(myValues);
        rv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
```

Comment: No, the item was removed, but when I went back to the activity again the item was existing, I mean the item came back again.

Comment: bcuz it not getting delete from database check your query

Comment: I put my Database delete method above in the description, you can check it.

Comment: you are fetching the database Id or not in your list

Comment: How can I check ?

Comment: Post the code for retrive the data from database and your model class

Comment: I added them. You can check

Comment: Do getInt to getString(3)

Comment: Tried it but error on starting the activity. Unfortunately App has stopped.

Comment: Add your project to github and mail me the link at faizmir53@gmail.com  for further help..You got your answer for postion

Comment: Actually my main problem was to delete an item from the database. But no one could solve it and I want to solve it here so the others can benefit from the solutions, not only for me.

Answer (score 0):

make following changes:

```
dataAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }
            MyActionModeCallBack mActionModeCallBack = new MyActionModeCallBack(position, dbh);
            mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

then define MyActionModeCallBack class like following:

```
public class MyActionModeCallBack extends ActionMode.Callback{
    int position;
    DatabaseHelper dbh;

   public MyActionModeCallBack(int position, dbh){
       this.position = position;
       this.dbh = dbh;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
       mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.delete:
               dbh.delete(position);// what ever your getter setter name is
               myValues.remove(position);
               dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               mode.finish();
               return true;

           case R.id.edit:
               Toast.makeText(ViewList.this, "Edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               mode.finish();
               return true;

           default:
               return false;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
       mActionMode = null;
   }
};
```

Comment: mActionModeCallBack = new MyActionModeCallBack(position, dbh);

Cannot resolve symbol 'mActionModeCallBack'

Comment: @AbdallahBedo this will not delete the data from database

Comment: put MyActionModeCallBack before mActionModeCallBack

Comment: Put them but it removed the item from the list and resets it again when I come back to the activity

Comment: It's another problem, you looked for a way to access position, you can create new question and related code snippets, or share your project on Github for me to check it

Comment: If you have a quick solution for it please add it. I have been working on this little project for more than a month

Comment: Actually my main problem was to delete an item from the database. But no one could solve it and I want to solve it here so the others can benefit from the solutions, not only for me.

Comment: I'm checking the problem, i think you have a neat issue which is hidden from eyes. may be it is some thing related to reference handling,

Answer (score 0):

Make a few changes to make code working with multiple selected values.

Add the following code into your activity class:-

```
private boolean multiSelect = false;
private ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

void selectItem(Integer item) {
  if (multiSelect) {
    if (selectedItems.contains(item)) {
       selectedItems.remove(item);
       } 
        else {
       selectedItems.add(item);
       }
  }
}

 private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallbacks = new ActionMode.Callback() {

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    multiSelect = true;
    menu.add("Delete");
   return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
   return false;

 }

 @Override
 public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
 for (Integer intItem : selectedItems) {
       myValues.remove(intItem);
      // pass the long id of the item seleted in the delete method. 
      int c = dbh.delete(myValues.get(intItem).getId());  
      if(c >0) { // deleted}
      else { // not deleted }         

  }

  mode.finish();

  return true;   
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

   multiSelect = false;
   selectedItems.clear();
   notifyDataSetChanged();

 }

};
```

Change the `setOnItemClickListener` as below:-

```
dataAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        if (mActionMode != null) {
            return false;
        }
        mActionMode = startSupportActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
        selectItem(position);  
        return true;
    }
});
```

Please make few  changes as per your menu in `onCreateActionMode` and `onActionItemClicked`.

All the seleted items will be add to the arraylist , it can be used for your different operations and the `boolean multiSelect` will allow you to unselect the already selected items.

For Reference:-
[Contextual Action Bars: Removing Items from a RecyclerView](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/contextual-action-bars-removing-items-recyclerview)

Try changing you delete function as follows :-

```
public int delete(long id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
int count= db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "id = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
return count;    // no. of rows deleted 
}
```

Actionbar callback flow :-

The first method is `onCreateActionMode`. This method is called once when the ActionMode is first created and is where we should set up the Menu.Also, since this is called when we’re first entering the ActionMode(on long pressing a item), it’s a good place to set our ‘multiSelect’ variable.

Moving onto `‘onPrepareActionMode’`, this method will be called anytime the CAB is invalidated. So if you want to update your CAB while it’s being displayed, this would be the place to do it, and you’d want to return true to tell Android that you’ve updated the CAB, otherwise if you do not need to update leave it as same.

`onActionItemClicked`this method is called whenever one of your CAB’s MenuItems is clicked.we need to do all the  delete operations here on the selected items and then call `mode.finish()`, which tells Android that we’re done with the CAB and results in a call to `onDestroyActionMode`.

`onDestroyActionMode` ,after this point the CAB will no longer be displayed, so this is a good spot to set ‘multiSelect’ to false as well as clear out our ‘selectedItems’ list. It’s also a good place to call ‘notifyDataSetChanged()’ to make sure that we’re keeping our adapter up to date with our ‘items’ List:

note :- CAB here denotes our contextual action bar.

Replace:-

Cursor data = dbh.getListContents();

```
if (data.getCount() != 0) {
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        String str1 = data.getString(1);
        String str2 = data.getString(2);
        long id = data.getLong(0);      // add this ,line gets the id 
        Data d = new Data(str1, str2);  
        d.setId(id);                    //set the id
        myValues.add(d);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(myValues);
        rv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I did not get the part of ActionMode.Callback, can you explain what would happen in this method ?

Comment: have tried to explain the functions , please see the edits.

Comment: Greate, but my problem with the delete method. I tried your way but the same problem, it is removed from the list only but not from the database so after deleting when I come back to the same activity I find that the item is reset again.

Comment: try to see what the delete funtion is returning because if it returns 0 , it means that nothing is being deleted.

Comment: please check your addData() , its it adding only two columns and id is not being added,  hence when you are trying to delete by id , it is not deleting any row since it does not find the id and results in same rows being get everytime.

Comment: I added all my codes above, you can check it and catch the problem

Comment: Because I am dispaired after all these tries

Comment: can you check it now?

Comment: Ok, in this case I will have also to add the number of the id which means I will have to add a new edittext to get the number of the id from it and insert it into the contentvalues.

Comment: Soory to confuse you, but just saw that your  id is auto incrementing , so you do not need to enter it into database like I showed befor. But yes u would have to get it, and set it to the items to be  shown in the list.

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem or I can delete the whole project ?

Comment: added it above, just make this change sure it should work with it.